# panning not working correctly in mapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid, android-framelayout, touch-event

I have mapView and I programatically handle the touch events.

The problem is: if the mapview is ZoomOut to its maximum, the panning is quite small and slow, and conforming the mapView is ZoomIn, the panning is bigger and faster. In another words: bigger the zoomIN bigger the panning movements.

How can I make panning moves not accordingly to zoom , so every time I move the map, it moves the same distance no matter the zoom level?

Here is my android Client

```
private double savedTouchedX = -1;
private double savedTouchedY = -1;
....

mapView.setOnTouchListener(new MapView.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

         switch(action)
         {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedTouchedX = event.getX();
                savedTouchedY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                doPanning(event, mapView);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                doPanning(event, mapView);
                savedTouchedX = -1;
                savedTouchedY = -1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
         }
         return true;
    }
});
```

....

```
//move mapView
private boolean doPanning(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView)
{
if(savedTouchedX >= 0 && savedTouchedY >= 0)
{
    IGeoPoint mapCenter = mapView.getMapCenter();
    GeoPoint panToCenter = new GeoPoint((int)(mapCenter.getLatitudeE6() + (e.getY() - savedTouchedY) * 1E5),
    (int)(mapCenter.getLongitudeE6() - (e.getX() - savedTouchedX) * 1E5));
    mapView.getController().setCenter(panToCenter);
}
savedTouchedX = e.getX();
savedTouchedY = e.getY();
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on TouchEvent, move the map programmatically

```
yourFrameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v , MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});

SimpleOnGestureListener listener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1 , MotionEvent e2 , float velocityX , float velocityY) {

        float Xdirection = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
        float Ydirection = e1.getY() - e2.getY();

        //TODO- Do some calculations & change the maps lat & lon. 
        // Also consider zoom level while calculating.

        final double newLat = (getOldLat - (moveSomeLatBasedOnXDirection)));
        final double newLon = (getOldLon - (moveSomeLatBasedOnYDirection)));

        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng( newLat, newLon));

        map.moveCamera(center);


        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    };

};
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), listener);
```

Comment: Right now I am using this code , and it works but only if the upper image is not visible, but If I cover the mapview with the image, it does not work: `m = MotionEvent.obtain(226707,226707,2/*ACTION_MOVE*/,x,y,0);       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {memecontentView.dispatchTouchEvent(m);} });`     Is there a way to make this same code works even if the mapview is not visible ? or the only way is to programmatically move the mapview?

Comment: I got it working , I updated my code. @VenomVendor do you How can I make panning moves not accordingly to zoom , so every time I move the map, it moves the same distance no matter the zoom level?

Comment: @user3805972 not sure, I haven't tried it. But you can.

Answer (score 0):

This hide your view. And disable touch on it. Actually that what you need.

```
 memecontentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This show view.

```
memecontentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
memecontentView.bringToFront();
```

To move to another layout

```
public void moveView(View view,ViewGroup destination) {
    ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
     //Also you can set LayoutParams here
     destination.addView(src);
     destination.getChildAt(destination.indexOf(src)).bringToFront();
}
```

Usage :

```
moveView(mapView,yourFrameLayout);
```

Comment: thanks, but my question is not how  to hide content. My question is: how to move the mapView even if it is hidden with an upper image in the frameLayout.My code handles the touch events if the map is not hidden, but what I do need, is to modify the image in Background

Comment: I meant: I have a mapview in client and I send it to server. the mapview should not be visible in client only in server, that is why I covered it with an image, but mapview should be able to react to the return touch events from server. In another words, I need to render the mapview as an image in background and send it to server. The thing is , If I cover mapview it does not move. so my question is How do I move mapview that is in background?

Answer (score 0):

"I need to cover the map with another image"

=> Not full sure to understand how this other image should behave.

If you set it as an [OSMBonusPack GroundOverlay](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_5), it will be drawn above the map. The map will react to all events (pan, zoom), and this upper image will also move according to map moves.

If this upper image should not move according to map moves, then you can implement a new (but quite simple) overlay, drawing your image at a fixed location on the mapview. Its draw method should be:

```
@Override protected void draw(Canvas c, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
  if (shadow)
    return;
  canvas.drawBitmap(myImage, screenX, screenY, null);
}
```

Comment: I meant: I have a mapview in client and I send it to server. the mapview should not be visible in client only in server, that is why I covered it with an image, but mapview should be able to react to the return touch events from server. In another words, I need to render the mapview as an image in background and send it to server. The thing is , If I cover mapview it does not move. so my question is How do I move mapview that is in background?

Comment: right now I am using this code , and it works but only if the upper image is not visible, but If I cover the mapview with the image, it does not work: `m = MotionEvent.obtain(226707,226707,2/*ACTION_MOVE*/,x,y,0);
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
           memecontentView.dispatchTouchEvent(m);
          }
      });`

Comment: OK, I see. So my second suggestion should work: you can hide your map with a new custom overlay, as I described. The map will still react to events. BTW, you could dispatch your event directly to mapView, instead of memecontentView?

Comment: I got it working , I updated my code. @MKer do you How can I make panning moves not accordingly to zoom , so every time I move the map, it moves the same distance no matter the zoom level?

Comment: Moving the client map based on events built on an server will not be reliable. Same screen resolution on both sides? Same orientation? If you want something reliable, just send from server to client: the map center, and the zoom level. Easy to get, easy to set (even if the map is hidden), 100% reliable.

Comment: The thing is I can **not modify server**, only client. Actually code  is working pretty good if upper image is not visible (`topImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`) , but when I delete this line (as needed) I can zoomIn/zoomOut map, but **panning stops working**